# Can one classify the conformal embeddings of the Riemann sphere into four dimensional Euclidean space?

Tags: complex-geometry, conformal-geometry

I am interested in conformally embedding the Riemann sphere into four dimensional Euclidean space.  One can trivially embed the Riemann sphere into three dimensions by identifying the usual sphere with the Riemann sphere.  I think it should be possible to also embed it as an ellipse.  I am wondering if those embeddings are unique, and if not whether they have been classified.  I have looked into it and have not found any papers looking into this.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that all Riemannian metrics on the 2D sphere are conformally isomorphic?

Comment: Yes I know that.  I was interested in embeddings in higher dimensional space, where the induced metric is conformally equivalent to the unique conformal metric on the Riemann sphere.  I know you can trivially embed the Riemann sphere into four dimensions, but was wondering if there are any nontrivial embeddings, and if so what are they (I've actually been getting some preliminary results on this, but not a definitive answer. I think I have almost enough to move forward with what is necessary for my purposes, maybe a weaker result but probably enough.)

Comment: my point is that any smoith embedding of the 2-sphere results (via pull back) in the standard conformal structure on the sphere. In particular, conformal embeddings are very far from being unique.

Comment: Oh ok I see your point, yes I misunderstood what you were saying.  So basically the question is trivial, because any embedding works.  I think I have a slightly different question in mind, motivated by Clifford algebras, but I thought this was equivalent.  My real question has more to do with Clifford algebra valued functions on defined on the Riemann sphere, but I think I'm figuring out the answer to that question more or less, so don't worry about it.

Comment: Actually I'm a little bit confused.  Why are the conformal maps from the Riemann sphere to itself so rigid if all metrics are conformally isomorphic?  my understanding is that conformal maps are the same as maps that preserve the conformal metric.

Comment: I do not think there is an easy answer to this question, both statements are theorems, the uniqueness (up to isomorphism) of conformal structure on $S^2$ is harder, the fact that automorphisms of $S^2$ are all Moebius is easier. While the first is false in dimensions $>2$, the second still holds for higher-dimensional round spheres.

Comment: Ok, cool thanks, yeah that makes sense.  I'm going to ask another question about holomorphic embeddings into projective space, which is more relevant to my problem in fact.